# How to publish Pelican documents with a different file extension?

Tags: pelican

I do want to setup pelican in such way that it will allow me to compile static markdown files by keeping their location but changing the compiled file extensions on the destination.

Here is an example:

```
 content/about.md    --> output/about.html
 content/foo/bar.md  --> output/foo/bar.html
```

Inside config I tried these:

```
PAGE_URL = '{path}.html'
PAGE_SAVE_AS = '{path}.html'
ARTICLE_URL = '{path}.html'
ARTICLE_SAVE_AS = '{path}.html'
```

The problem is that the `.md` part is not removed and that `{path}` contains the entire path with the filename.

I know that I could use the `{slug}` and manually enter the slug inside bug that's not cool at all as it would require me to add a slug for each page.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this in your pelican configuration:

```
FILENAME_METADATA = '(?P<slug>.*)'  # use markdown file name as the slug meta
USE_FOLDER_AS_CATEGORY = True       # use folder name as posts' category

ARTICLE_URL = '{category}/{slug}.html'
ARTICLE_SAVE_AS = ARTICLE_URL
PAGE_URL = '{slug}.html'
PAGE_SAVE_AS = PAGE_URL
CATEGORY_URL = '{slug}/index.html'
CATEGORY_SAVE_AS = CATEGORY_URL
```

For details about these variables, see http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.1.1/settings.html